# GraphQL + PreAuthorize on Controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, graphql

I really encountered a strange situation.

When using graphql and having @PreAuthorize at controller layer , i will receive access denied every time even if i'm testing and using @WithMockUser , but when changing the annotation to the service layer, suddenly everything works. Why?

***Test:***

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Import(TestSecurityConfig.class)
public class VehileControllerGraphQLIT implements TestBase {

    @Autowired
    private GraphQLTestTemplate graphQLTestTemplate;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        var wm = new WireMockServer(options().port(8080));
        wm.start();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(authorities = "ADMIN")
    public void getAllVehicles_success() throws IOException {



        var vehicle = TestBase.createVehicleDto();
        List<VehicleDto> vehicles = Collections.singletonList(vehicle);


        WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.get(ELASTICO_URL + "/vehicles")
                        .withQueryParam("page", WireMock.equalTo("0"))
                        .withQueryParam("size", WireMock.equalTo("10"))
                .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .withBody("[{\"id\":1,\"brand\":\"Mercedes\",\"model\":\"E class\"}]")));


        var response = graphQLTestTemplate.postForResource("graphql/getAllVehicles.graphql");
        assertThat(response.isOk()).isTrue();
        var vehicleList = response.get("$.data");
        
    }



}
```

***Spring Config ( main )***

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http,
                                                       PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) throws Exception {

        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .userDetailsService(userService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .and()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain  securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Enable CORS and disable CSRF
        http = http.csrf().disable();

        // Set session management to stateless
        http = http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and();

        // Set unauthorized requests exception handler
        http = http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(
                        (request, response, ex) -> {
                            response.sendError(
                                    HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                                    ex.getMessage()
                            );
                        }
                )
                .and();

        // Set permissions on endpoints
        http.authorizeRequests()
                // Our public endpoints
                .antMatchers("/auth/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/initPasswordReset").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/auth/resetPassword").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/graphiql").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/graphql").permitAll()
                // Our private endpoints
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Add JWT token filter
        http.addFilterBefore(
                jwtTokenFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
        );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityContextLogoutHandler securityContextLogoutHandler() {
        return new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
    }

}
```

***Spring Config ( Test )***

```
  @TestConfiguration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class TestSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/graphql").hasAnyAuthority()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http,
                                                       PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) throws Exception {

        return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
                .userDetailsService(userService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .and()
                .build();
    }
}
```

***Controller:***

```
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@Validated
public class VehicleControllerGraphQl {

    private final CoreService coreService;
    private final ElasticoService elasticoService;

    @QueryMapping()
    public List<VehicleDto> getAllVehicles(@Argument(name = "page") @DefaultValue("0") int page,
                                           @Argument(name = "size") @DefaultValue("10") int size) {
        return elasticoService.getAllVehicles(page, size);
    }
}
```

***Schema Graphql:***

```
 type VehicleDto {
    id: ID!
    vin: String!
    brand: String!
    model: String!
    generation: String!
    colour: String!
    productionDate: String!
    km: String!
    fuel: String!
    power: Int!
    cylindricalCapacity: Int!
    transmission: TransmissionType!
    traction: TractionType!
    country: String!
    firstRegistrationDate: String!
    firstOwner: String!
    accidentFree: Boolean!
    tvaDeductible: Boolean!
    createdAt: String!
}

type AccountDto {
    id: ID!
    username: String
    name: String
    address: String
    registrationNumber: String
    phoneNumber: String
    registeredSince: String
}

input VehicleInput {
    id: ID!
    vin: String!
    brand: String!
    model: String!
    generation: String!
    colour: String!
    productionDate: String!
    km: String!
    fuel: String!
    power: Int!
    cylindricalCapacity: Int!
    transmission: TransmissionType!
    traction: TractionType!
    country: String!
    firstRegistrationDate: String!
    firstOwner: String!
    accidentFree: Boolean!
    tvaDeductible: Boolean!
}

input AccountInput {
    id: ID
    username: String!
    name: String!
    address: String!
    registrationNumber: String!
    phoneNumber: String!
}

input VehicleCriteriaInput {
    brand: String
    model: String
    productionDate: String
    fuel: String
    transmission: TransmissionType
    traction: TractionType
    country: String
    firstRegistrationDate: String
}

enum TransmissionType {
    AUTOMATIC
    MANUAL
}

enum TractionType {
    FWD
    RWD
    AWD
}

type User {
    id: ID!
    username: String!
    role: Role!
    mail: String!
}

enum Role {
    ROLE_ADMIN,
    ROLE_STANDARD_USER
}

input UserInput {
    username: String!
    role: Role!
    password: String!
    mail: String!
}

input LoginCredentialsInput {
    username: String
    password: String
}

input PasswordResetTokenInput {
    token: String!
    email: String!
    newPassword: String!
}

type Query {

    # User vehicle queries
    getAllVehicles(page: Int, size: Int): [VehicleDto]!
    searchVehiclesByTerm(term: String!, page: Int, size: Int): [VehicleDto]!
    searchVehiclesByCriteria(vehicleCriteria: VehicleCriteriaInput!, page: Int, size: Int): [VehicleDto]!
    getVehicle(vehicleId: ID!): VehicleDto
    getOwnedVehiclesForAccount(accountId: ID!, page: Int, size: Int): [VehicleDto]!
    getFavoriteVehiclesForAccount(accountId: ID!, page: Int, size: Int): [VehicleDto]!

    # User account queries
    getAccount(accountId: ID!): AccountDto!

    # Auth queries
    getUser(userId: ID!): User
}

type Mutation {

    # User vehicle mutations
    createVehicleForAccount(vehicle: VehicleInput!, accountId: ID!): VehicleDto
    updateVehicle(vehicle: VehicleInput!, vehicleId: ID!): VehicleDto
    deleteVehicleFromAccount(vehicleId: ID!, accountId: ID!): Boolean
    addFavoriteVehicleForAccount(vehicleId: ID!, accountId: ID!): Boolean
    deleteFavoriteVehicleFromAccount(vehicleId: ID!, accountId: ID!): Boolean

    # Admin vehicle mutations
    updateAnyVehicleForAccount(vehicleDto: VehicleInput!, vehicleId: ID!): VehicleDto
    deleteAnyVehicleFromAccount(vehicleId: ID!, accountId: ID!): Boolean

    # User account mutations
    createAccount(accountDto: AccountInput!): AccountDto!
    removeOwnAccount(accountId: ID!): Boolean
    updateOwnAccount(accountDto: AccountInput!, accountId: ID!): AccountDto

    # Admin account mutation
    updateAnyAccount(accountDto: AccountInput, accountId: ID!): AccountDto
    removeAnyAccount(accountId: ID): Boolean

    # Auth mutations
    register(userDto: UserInput!): String
    login(loginCredentials: LoginCredentialsInput!): String
    logout: Boolean
    initPasswordReset(email: String!): Boolean
    finishPasswordReset(passwordResetDto: PasswordResetTokenInput!):` Boolean
    changeMail(mail: String!): Boolean
    changePassword(newPasswordCredentials: LoginCredentialsInput!): Boolean``
}
```

***Service***

```
 public class ElasticoService {

    private final ElasticoAdapter elasticoAdapter;

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_VEHICLE')")
    public List<VehicleDto> getAllVehicles(int page, int size) {
        return elasticoAdapter.getAllVehicles(page, size);
    }
```

! Appearently this does not work on service either, everytime a graphql request pops in, the autentication is always an annoymus user w/e i do . Even if i do @WithMockedUser or mock user details service and so on.

Comment: share your code.

Comment: just did and i realized that appearently this does not work on service either, everytime a graphql request pops in, the autentication is always an annoymus user w/e i do . Even if i do @WithMockedUser or mock user details service and so on.